# Google hangouts conversation id

Tags: google-assist-api, google-hangouts

I am building a home assistant and i want it to send me messages on Google Hangouts, but one of the parameters it requires is conversation id which I can't find anywhere. Does anyone have any experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here looking for this information too, but as it turns out, you don't have to search for the ID in your HangOuts but in your Hass interface:

https://www.home-assistant.io/components/hangouts/#finding-the-conversation-id

The ID is in the developer tools provided in your Hass installation. Look in the "Status" tab. If the information doesn't show up, try refreshing going to the "Services" tab, select "hangouts.reconnect" and then press "Call Service". You should now see the conversation ID under the "Status" tab.